# I'm trying to make an error message for the combo in vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(YearBox.Text)) Then
   MessageBox.Show("Please select a year group")
End If
```

The code above is showing what I have done, I am trying to make sure that when a user submits their details and doesn't select a year group that message pops up (which it does correctly). But when they have selected a year group the message still appears thus not allowing them to submit their details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if user selected something or not, use this syntax

```
If YearBox.SelectedIndex < 0 Then ' Nothing Selected
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a year group")
End If
```